# How can I speed up using Pytorch DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I had a dataset including about a million of rows. Before,  I read the rows, preprocessed data and created a list of rows to be trained. Then I defined a Dataloader over this data like:

```
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mydata['train'],
        batch_size=node_batch_size,shuffle=shuffle,collate_fn=data_collator)
```

Preprocessing could be time consuming, so I thought to define an [IterableDataSet](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset) with `__iter__` function. Then I could define my Dataloader like:

```
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(myds['train'],
        batch_size=node_batch_size,shuffle=shuffle,collate_fn=data_collator)
```

However, still to begin training it seems that it calls my preprocessing function and creates an Iteration over it. So, it seems I didn't gain much speed up.

Please guide me how could I use speed up in this case?

Here is my part of my class:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        iter_start = self.start
        iter_end = self.num_samples
        worker_info = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()
        if worker_info is None:  # single-process data loading, return the full iterator
             iter_start = self.start
             iter_end = self.num_samples
        else:  # in a worker process
             # split workload
             per_worker = int(math.ceil((self.num_samples - self.start) / float(worker_info.num_workers)))
             worker_id = worker_info.id
             iter_start = self.start + worker_id * per_worker
             iter_end = min(iter_start + per_worker, self.num_samples)
        if self.flat_data:
            return iter(self.flat_data)
        else:
            return iter(self.fill_data(iter_start, iter_end))

    def fill_data(self, iter_start, iter_end, show_progress=False):
        flat_data = []
        if iter_end < 0:
            iter_end = self.num_samples
        kk = 0 
        dlog.info("========================== SPLIT: %s", self.split_name)
        dlog.info("get data from %s to %s", iter_start, iter_end)
        dlog.info("total rows: %s", len(self.split_df))
        if show_progress:
            pbar = tqdm(total = self.num_samples)

        for index, d in self.split_df.iterrows():
            if kk < iter_start:
                dlog.info("!!!!!!!!! before start %s", iter_start)
                kk += 1
                continue
            rel = d["prefix"]
            ...
            # preprocessing and adding to returned list
```

Comment: Could you give more details about your dataset class ? Have you access to gpus ? What kind of data are you using (image, text etc...) ?

Comment: @MaxD. I provided more of the code! Maybe I should use an iterator for dataframe...

Comment: What is the preprocessing? If it looks the same for a given data example every time you run it, run it once and cache the preprocessed data in say a pickle file. Only compute at runtime preprocessing steps that are not able to be defined a priori

Comment: @DerekG I do preprosessing in the `fill_data` . However, I found the solution. I must use  a `map` for preprocessing. Then the preprocessing is called during trainig and for every batch and not before training.

Answer (score 0):

I did preprosessing in the `fill_data` or `__iter__` body. However, I can use a map for preprocessing. Then the preprocessing is called during training and for every batch and not before training.

```
import pandas as pd
import torch

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, fname, until=10):
        self.df = pd.read_table("atomic/" + fname)
        self.until = until
    def preproc(self, t):
        prefix, data = t
        text = "Preproc: " + prefix + "|" + data
        print(text) # to check when it is called
        return text

    def __iter__(self):
        _iter = self.df_iter()
        return map(self.preproc, _iter)

    def df_iter(self):
        ret = []
        for idx, row in self.df.iterrows():
             ret.append((row["prefix"],row["input_text"]))
        return iter(ret)
```